Include nginx in github actions automation to assign domain name to ip and port using reverse proxy using config files
How to unclude nginx in github actions automation to assign domain name to ip and port  using reverse proxy using custom config files and ssl certificates
I want to include the conf file and ssl certificate either as a variable or in the code in the repository I am unable to do it
